# How to differentiate user-login session variables and other session variables

Tags: php, arrays, session, yii

I'm using sessions in my PHP web application, for a single users, I need to store login session (session array/variables) such as username, a flag to denote whether the user is logged in, etc.

Another session (array/variables) is of Search-page where I have a range of variables. I thought of assigning an array to the `$_SESSION`, as a variable with all the values. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an session array such as -

```
 $_SESSSION['loginSessions'] = array();
```

then you can assign values to your `loginSessions` as -

```
 $_SESSSION['loginSessions']['flag'] = true;
 $_SESSSION['loginSessions']['userid'] = "...";
```

This will separate your session variables from other sessions.

For unsetting the session array -

```
foreach($_SESSSION['loginSessions'] as $key=>$value) 
{ 
   unset($_SESSSION['loginSessions'][$key]); 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply Chandan. How to reset those different sessions?

Comment: you can unset the specific session `unset( $_SESSSION['loginSessions']['flag'])`

Comment: for reseting the entire array, you can iterate over the array and `unset` the variables.

Comment: Is there we needs to define a session_id or session_register or session_name like things. To differentiate these session. As you described can be used in PHP core, I am using Yii framework?

Comment: you might want to look at this for yii framework specific - http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/42403-remove-item-from-session-array/

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? you can just use data from the database as a unique identifier for a user:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_data'] = array('username'=>$username, 'user_id'=>$user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone says, session is a way for storing user-specific information.
See this [here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Sessions-and-Cookies/) also for more information about sessions and cookies. 
I also have the same requirements to manage two sessions in two different array and even if user logged out as a user the second array should exist there. What I tried is to manage the session value into $_cookies = $_session an then reverts back those cookie into session. Well although I didn't tried this using the Yii 1.1 framework.